# How to create a popup window for confirmation while exiting an app in android when working wth multiple activities

Tags: android, popup, exit

I'm working with many activities in Android.
What I need is, while exiting the app, it should pop up a confirmation to exit or not.
I know to create a popup window without using any .xml file only in java.
I also know how to do the following thing while working with only one activity or from a click event.
But in case of multiple activities and by clicking back button, it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should only ask user about exiting on your Main (Launcher Activity) because back button should always get user back to previous activity if any. And if you want to do this you should override activity's onBackPressed() method. You have to implement onBackPressed() on all your activities if you want to give options in all activities or just in launcher activity if you want to give on launcher activity. here is example .

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    AlertDialog.Builder ab = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    ab.setTitle("myDialog");
    ab.setMessage("are you sure to exit?");
    ab.setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            //if you want to kill app . from other then your main avtivity.(Launcher)
            android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
            System.exit(1);

            //if you want to finish just current activity

            yourActivity.this.finish();
        }
    });
    ab.setNegativeButton("no", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    ab.show();
}
```

other Solution (But a Bit heavy):
in your parent activity's oncereate.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("closeornot", false)) {
     finish();
}
//after this you can write any other code.
}
```

And in your other (Child Activities) use onBackPressed as this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  Intent mIntent = new Intent(yourActivity.this, Home.class);
   mIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
   mIntent.putExtra("closeotnot", true);
   startActivity(mIntent);
 }
```

Comment: Tried this but it is not killing the entire app. `Process.killProcess(Process.myPid);` is not killing the entire app. It is also closing the current activity and returning the control to the 'previous activity.

Comment: I updated my answer. check if it solves the problem. please accept this.

Comment: I also think it gonna be a heavy stuff cause as it seems you've redirected the control to the `Home.class` and after reaching `Home.class` it is checking for the control in `onCreate()` and then clsing it.

I have a solution though. It is not clearing the app totally but what it is doing is it is bringing the home screen of the mobile to the top of the stack.

    `Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
finish();`

Comment: Yes, But when it is being redirected it will finish app if you have passed exit data on onBackPressed() method. So it will check and finish the app before creating its view it won't be that heavy as you think.

Comment: Your code seems perfect to me, but unfortunately `if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("closeornot", false)) { finish(); }` is not working.

Sice I'm new in android platform so, I don't the exact uses of these intents.

If you guide me, it would be very helpful to me.

Comment: Basically You use intents to move from one activity to other and passing data from one activity to other on base of which you can take decisions .Here is link where you can read all the documentation for android.         http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Comment: Bro at last it worked. I had to combine few ideas into yours and it is working great. The problem I was facing was that once I exit the app if I start it again, it was not opening from the first page. And I don't needed that. Used your redirecting idea and cleared everything with mine & now its working fine.

Comment: Ok. That's Great. :)